# HDD not bootable. Folder still exists, but with no data

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

my HDD refuses to boot (Windows 7).

I started the SystemRescueCD and discovered the following (I had 3 logical partitions(

```
ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows
Error reading bootsector : Input/output error
...
ntfs-3g /dev/sda3 /mnt/windows
..
du -hsk *
...
95G   found.000
```

Well, this `found.000` contains very valuable data for me (listed in a subfolder `dir0001.chk`). In windows the folder which contained the data is still listed, but as an empty folder. With my SystemRescueCD listing the `dir0001.chk` folder shows the data Im missing.

So, my questions are :

1. How this mess had happened ?
2. I to rescued my disappeared data (listed in the dir0001.chk) ... just by copying it out of the `dir0001.chk` folder ... any other better suggestions are appreciated ?

Best regards,

Comment: Have you tried plugging your HDD into another computer (With windows OS) and use Recuva?

Comment: I did but with no Recuva (never heard of it). Thats how I rescued the data. However, the questions how this has happened and if there is a better way for rescuing remains.